# How to open a link with a UIButton within a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, hyperlink, uibutton

I have created the below code to display buttons in `UITableView`. I want to add click event for every particular cell in table to reach to google links by clicking into that button.
How to add to clicking events into the buttons options for particular cell and to reach google link?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UIButton *button =[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5,40,40)];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonpressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lori"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTag:9001];
    [cell addSubview:button];
    [cell setIndentationWidth:45];
    [cell setIndentationLevel:1];
    cell.textLabel.text = [thearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(void) buttonpressed:(UIButton *)sender {}
```

Comment: Woah... something wrong with your formatting there.

Comment: ya i know i am not getting ..how to put spase between to it.but can u understand?

Comment: Nope, it's just not readable.

Comment: Your code seems a little strange. I removed the second method since it does not make sense. In this manner other people could understand the code. P.S. If you want you can rollback to a previous version of your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like:

```
-(void) buttonpressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSString* launchUrl = @"http://apple.com/";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: launchUrl]];
}
```

this will open safari pointing to the URL you pass in.

If you do not want to open safari, then you should display your own `UIWebView`.

Furthermore, you might want to add your button to `contentView`:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];
```

Comment: thanks! and the code u mentioned is for particular button only ..I Want for each cell view code.how to call for multiple buttons

Comment: You can use the `UIButton` tag that you associate to each button to know which button was pressed and thus which URL to open.